# Expect that all elements in a Seq throws exception in specs2

Tags: scala, specs2

I want to perform some basic validation of the arguments given to a `User` class' constructor, by throwing an `IllegalArgumentException` if the validation fails. In this case it is an email address that I want to validate.

In order to test the validation, I want to test few valid email addresses and expect that **none** of them cause the exception to be thrown. I also want to test a few invalid email addresses and expect that **all** of them cause the exception to be thrown.

This is my code so far, for the invalid email addresses:

```
def throwException = throwAn[IllegalArgumentException].like {
  case e => e.getMessage must contain("Invalid email")
}

Seq(
  new User("Valid name", "joe@@multipleAtSigns.com"),
  new User("Valid name", "a?<bunch>[of]special{characters}@validdomain.tld"),
  new User("Valid name", "withoutanyatsign"),
  new User("Valid name", "123@456.789NumbersInTLD"),
  new User("Valid name", "recepientWithoutDomain@"),
  new User("Valid name", "@NoRecepient")
) must contain(throwException).foreach
```

The reason I placed them in a `Seq` was simply convenience; I don't want to have to write `must throwException` after each, like so:

```
new User("Valid name", "joe@@multipleAtSigns.com") must throwException
new User("Valid name", "a?<bunch>[of]special{characters}@validdomain.tld") must throwException
new User("Valid name", "withoutanyatsign") must throwException
new User("Valid name", "123@456.789NumbersInTLD") must throwException
new User("Valid name", "recepientWithoutDomain@") must throwException
new User("Valid name", "@NoRecepient") must throwException
```

My problem is that I get an error when running the tests, which is caused by a thrown exception:

```
[error]    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid email: joe@@multipleAtSigns.com (User.scala:16)
```

So the problem is that I actually *expect* the above exception to be thrown, and I want my tests to consider a thrown exception successful, but instead the tests errors.

I can understand why the test errors, so I'm basically wondering if there is any workaround for this. Or maybe I have misunderstood how matchers on `Traversable`s work?

Answer (score 0):

Traversable matchers assume that the collection they are evaluating is not itself throwing an exception. This is the case here since some (or all) users put in the `Seq` will throw an exception. The following will work:

```
Seq(
  () => new User("Valid name", "joe@@multipleAtSigns.com"),
  () => new User("Valid name", "a?<bunch>[of]special{characters}@validdomain.tld"),
  () => new User("Valid name", "withoutanyatsign"),
  () => new User("Valid name", "123@456.789NumbersInTLD"),
  () => new User("Valid name", "recepientWithoutDomain@"),
  () => new User("Valid name", "@NoRecepient")
) must contain((u: (() => User)) => u() must throwException).foreach
```

I would however suggest to put your validation method outside of the `User` class to leave the `User` class pure:

```
def validate(u: User): Unit = 
  // do the validation 
  ???
```

I would actually suggest to avoid exception altogether and have "smart" constructors for `Users`

```
// you don't even need exceptions :-)
def user(name: String, email: String): Either[UserCreationError, User] = 
  ???
```